# How to implement Blowfish CBC algorithm PKCS5 Padding in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, blowfish

I am trying to implement Blowfish Algorithm PKCS5 padding with CBC mode .

I am using the [FclBlowFish](https://github.com/cantecim/FclBlowfish) library.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Did you end up implementing it?

Comment: Yes I have Implement it .